# pgfplot - Vertical grid lines are going over axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

for whatever reason in this pgfplot the vertical grid lines are overlapping the axis (which looks ugly) even though I use a pretty similar axis for another plot where the grid lines don't overlap.
This is how it looks like:

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
        \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{socket_ltncy_30s_recvmsg_8x1080p50_24g.csv}\datatable
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ylabel near ticks,
            axis line style = thin,
            grid=major, grid style={gray!30},
            bar width=.01cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=3cm,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 150,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 100,
            xtick distance = {25},
            ytick distance = {25},
            yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
            xlabel={Latency in $\mu$s},
            ylabel={ \textcolor{black}{Percent} },
            label style={font=\scriptsize},
            bar shift=0mm
            ],
            \addplot[
              draw=black,
              fill=black,
              bar shift=0mm
            ] table [
                x={LATENCY},
                y={PERCENT},
                restrict expr to domain={y}{0.1:100}
              ]{\datatable};

            \addplot[
              scatter,
              only marks,
              mark=x,
              color=black,
              scatter/use mapped color={draw=black}
            ] table [
                x={LATENCY},
                y={PERCENT},
                restrict expr to domain={y}{0.000001:0.1}
            ]{\datatable};

            \addplot[
              draw=green,
              fill=green,
              bar shift=0mm
            ] table [
                x={LATENCY},
                y={PERCENT},
                restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{IS_MEDIAN}}{1:1}
              ]{\datatable};

            \addplot[
              draw=red,
              fill=red,
              bar shift=0mm
            ] table [
                x={LATENCY},
                y={PERCENT},
                restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{IS_MEAN}}{1:1}
              ]{\datatable};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

with data `socket_ltncy_30s_recvmsg_8x1080p50_24g.csv` looking something like this

```
LATENCY,PERCENT,IS_MEDIAN,IS_MEAN
2,8.04666667,0,0
3,9.87416667,1,1
4,23.75833333,0,0
5,0.65000000,0,0
6,0.54166667,0,0
7,0.62416667,0,0
8,0.59750000,0,0
9,0.14500000,0,0
10,0.05166667,0,0
11,0.05583333,0,0
12,0.05166667,0,0
13,0.05333333,0,0
14,0.05666667,0,0
15,0.04833333,0,0
16,0.05583333,0,0
17,0.06166667,0,0
18,0.06083333,0,0
19,0.05666667,0,0
20,0.05833333,0,0
```

I want them to "bend" inwards, like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the gridlines, but the ticks. Add `tick align=inside` to the `axis` options, *after* the `ybar` options. (`ybar` seems to set `xtick align=outside`, so you need to overwrite that setting.)

Irrelevant sidenotes: `pgfplots` loads `tikz` and therefore also `pgf`, so you don't need to explicitly load the latter two when you have `pgfplots`. And the `\centering` that is inside the `tikzpicture` environment doesn't actually do anything, I think, so you can remove that.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            %tick align=inside % uncomment this to see difference
            ]
            \addplot {rnd};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!